# como sacar un valor de una respuesta httpresponse que viene de nodejs en angular

Tags: angular

el backend me devuelve esto:

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3999/admin/upload-avatar", ok: true, …}
body: {status: "success", image: "teGxFW-wwKoqKLyKYrQAX9Td.png"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 4
url: "http://localhost:3999/admin/upload-avatar"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

como leer image: "teGxFW-wwKoqKLyKYrQAX9Td.png"} del body de la respuesta en angular?

desde el front usando la libreria angular file uploader

```
afuConfig: AngularFileUploaderConfig = {

  multiple: false,
  formatsAllowed: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif',
 // maxSize: '50' ,
  uploadAPI:{
    url: 'http://localhost:3999/admin/' + 'upload-avatar',
   //url:'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
    method: 'PUT',
   
    // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data boundary=???' },
   // headers:{
  //  'Authorization': this.token,
   // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data boundary=???'
   // }
    
  },


  theme: 'attachPin',
  hideProgressBar: false,
  hideResetBtn: true,
  hideSelectBtn: false,
 // attachPinText: ' Sube la imagen'
};
```

backend nodejs

```
uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {
        // Configurar el modulo multiparty (md) routes/user.js

        // Recoger el fichero de la petición
        var file_name = 'imagen no subida...';


        if (!req.files) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: file_name
            });
        }

        // Conseguir el nombre y la extension del archivo
        // var file_path = req.params.file0.path;
        var file = req.files.file0.path;


        console.log(file);
        // var path = file
        // var file_split = file_path.split('\\');

        // ** Adventencia ** En linux o mac
        var file_split = file.split('/');

        // Nombre del archivo
        var file_name = file_split[2];
        console.log(file_name);

        // Extensión del archivo
        var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
        console.log(ext_split);
        var file_ext = ext_split[1];
        console.log(file_ext);


        // Comprobar extension (solo imagenes), si no es valida borrar fichero subido
        if (file_ext != 'png' && file_ext != 'jpg' && file_ext != 'jpeg' && file_ext != 'gif') {
            fs.unlink(file, (err) => {

                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'La extensión del archivo no es valida.'
                });

            });

        } else {
            // Sacar el id del libro
            var params = req.files.file0.id;
            console.log(file_name);
            var bookId = req.params.bookId;
            console.log('bookid', bookId);


            // Devolver respuesta
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                image: file_name,

            });

            console.log(image);
        }

    },
```

en el frontend la funcion

```
upload(image)
{
    console.log(image);
    let data = image;
    console.log(data);

}
```

recibe la respuesta del backend

Comment: ¿Cómo realizas la petición?

Comment: con una liberia para subir imagenes al backend, ejecuto la funcion del backend que guarda la imagen y devuelve la respuesta con body image: kjwsdkjkjk.png

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código?

Answer (score 0):

he conseguido sacar el nombre de la respuesta asi

```
let name = data.body.image;
```